# Make same layout in Android

Tags: java, android

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx4ny.gif)

So, i want make same layout in my Android app.

I can't find this example on Google, maybe someone can help?

Comment: It's called [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). googling "Android material design" should give you plenty to read.

Answer (score 0):

To implement that layout, look at the Android Support Design Library. This includes tons of Material design widgets.

[About Support Design Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design)